# SQL Server Bulk Import - character translation?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a pipe delimited text file I am using BULK INSERT to import into a table in SQL Server.

I have had real problems with certain characters. For example, text that appears in the text file as "30º of tilt and 80º" gets imported as "30┬║ of tilt and 80┬║"

Now, the data in the text file was actually generated from another SQL Server database, and in the original table the string appears as "30º of tilt and 80º" so I'm somewhat baffled.

Both databases have the same collation. The SP I use to do the bulk insert is:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'BULK INSERT ' + @TempTable + ' FROM '''+@Sourcefile+''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=''|'',ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'');'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Which works fine in all other respects

Thanks

Comment: Tried forcing the code page for the bulk insert command to the code page of the collation used by the database - this changes the result to "30Âº of tilt and 80Âº"

Answer (score 0):

assuming @sourcefile is ANSI encoded, this should work:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'BULK INSERT ' + @TempTable + ' FROM '''+@Sourcefile+''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=''|'',ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'', CODEPAGE=''ACP'');'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I'd already tried that without success

Answer (score 0):

Figured it

The text file was not unicode encoded. Changing this sorted the problem